# Bounds on determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

I was just curious about the bounds on the determinant of a 3x3 matrix whose elements take values between 0 and 5.
I believe this bound is around +-1040

Comment: I get $\pm 375$ for elements in $[0,5]$.  I get $\pm 750$ for elements in $[-5,5]$.

Comment: You might want to re evaluate the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simulation of 1,000,000 random matrices for which the entries $A_{ij} \in (0,5)$ were uniformly distributed. The mean value of the determinant is 0.003774572, with standard deviation 23.31994. The **minimum** determinant was -160.43715 and the **maximum** 175.49375 . 
The following image shows the distribution adjusted by Epanechnikov kernel: 
[image]

I think your bounds are a bit off...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 250.

Here is a brute force approach.

Consider the function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \det \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{bmatrix}$. The function $f$ is continuous and the set $[0,5]^{3 \times 3}$ compact, so there is some maximiser of $f$, say $(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2, \hat{x}_3)$.

Now consider $f(\hat{x}_1+ \lambda e_k, \hat{x}_2, \hat{x}_3)= f(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2, \hat{x}_3) + \lambda f( e_k, \hat{x}_2, \hat{x}_3)$.

Let $\alpha = f( e_k, \hat{x}_2, \hat{x}_3)$.
If 
$\alpha = 0$, then we can replace $\hat{x}_1$ by
$\hat{x}_1+ \lambda e_k$ for any $\lambda$, hence we can choose $\lambda$ so
that the $k$th entry of $\hat{x}_1+ \lambda e_k$ is $0$ or $5$.

If $\alpha>0$, we can choose $\lambda$ so that the $k$th entry of $\hat{x}_1+ \lambda e_k$ is $5$.

If $\alpha<0$, we can choose $\lambda$ so that the $k$th entry of $\hat{x}_1+ \lambda e_k$ is $0$.

This analysis can be repeated for each column. Hence we can restrict our
search to the space $\{0,5\}^{3 \times 3}$. A quick examination of the $2^9$
matrices shows that the maximum is 250 and this is attained by, for example,
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 5 & 5 \\ 5 & 0 & 5 \\ 5 & 5 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Here is the Python program that examined the $2^9$ matrices:

```
import numpy
import itertools

cols = list(itertools.product((0 ,5), (0 ,5), (0 ,5)))
mats = itertools.product(cols, cols, cols)
sup = 0
sup_p = None
for p in mats:
    d = numpy.linalg.det(p)
    if d > sup:
        sup = d
        sup_p = p

print sup
print sup_p
```

Comment: I'm curious why this answer is not accepted given that it is the only one that actually answers the question? Or at least, why there is an accepted answer that doesn't answer the question?

Comment: This is indeed the best (and perhaps the only explicitly correct) answer so far. I'll give it a +1, but it does deserve more.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can expand the determinant. Here's one way to approach it (informally)...

For integers $a,\ldots,i\in[0,5]$, we define the matrix determinant
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{array}\right|=a(ei-fh)+b(fg-di)+c(dh-eg).$$

Since all the terms are non-negative, the product $P$ of any two entries is $0\le P \le 25$. Then, what can you say about the difference $ei-fh$ and the other two cofactor expressions?

From here, it should be clearer how to derive the bounds of the determinant. [feel free to comment if you have any questions or remarks]

EDIT: Of course, the entries need not be integers, as you mentioned. We can let $a,\ldots,i$ be any real numbers in the interval $[0,5]$, though the method above and its result are the same.

Comment: So how do we get precise bounds?

Comment: @RobArthan The above method will give the correct bounds of possible determinate values. It can be polished up some, probably with the $\max$ and $\min$ operators. Are you asking for a more direct, analytic method?

Comment: I was hoping for a direct analytical method. I got +-1040 from 1000 repetitions with random elements. Come to think of it, I think I used bounds [0, 10] on elements. Minimum should have the same magnitude as maximum because you can swap two rows to negate determinant.

Comment: +-(5x5x5 + 5x5x5 + 5x5x5 - 0x0x0 - 0x0x0 - 0x0x0) gives a rather loose bounds.